# How to get data with BeautifulSoup without having "None"?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I have a problem with it.

I want to get the name of the courses in specific search results on Udemy (from this link https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=veri+bilimi).

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=veri+bilimi")

print(result.status_code)

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

print(soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"udlite-focus-visible-target udlite-heading-md course-card--course-title--2f7tE"}))
```

It turns "None" instead of course names. Unfortunately, I didn't understand and see my mistake.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The udemy website is using javascript to load course title that requests won't access. You need to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
url ="https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=veri+bilimi"
import time
webdriver =webdriver.Chrome()

webdriver.get(url)
time.sleep(6) # delay 6 sec

soup = BeautifulSoup(webdriver.page_source, "lxml")

course_titles = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"udlite-focus-visible-target udlite-heading-md course-card--course-title--2f7tE"})
for title in course_titles:
    print(title.get_text())
```

[Selenium Installation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) if you need it.